# PSPDFKit UIImage from page (for saving)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, pdf-generation, pspdfkit

After I have loaded a PDF and drawn a few things, how do I get the resulting UIImage so that I can save it to the file system?

Answer (score 0):

Use [renderImageForPage:withSize:clippedToRect:withAnnotations:options:receipt:error:](http://pspdfkit.com/documentation/Classes/PSPDFDocument.html#//api/name/renderImageForPage%3awithSize%3aclippedToRect%3awithAnnotations%3aoptions%3areceipt%3aerror%3a) from your document object.